# WPF Data Binding: BindingOperations.SetBinding() do not use the value of the Dependency Property

Tags: wpf, data-binding, c#-3.0, dependency-properties

I have a own dependency property `Target.Height` bound to a normal property `Source.Height` using `BindingOperations.SetBinding()`. Updating the `Target.Height` property should update the `Source.Height` property.  But not the actual value of the dependency property is used rather the default value of the dependency property. Is this the intended behavior?

Thanks for any hints. Code I use:

```
public class Source
{
  private int m_height;
  public int Height
  {
    get { return m_height; }
    set { m_height = value; }
  }
}

public class Target : DependencyObject
{
  public static readonly DependencyProperty HeightProperty;

  static Target()
  {
    Target.HeightProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("Height", typeof(int), typeof(Target),
      new PropertyMetadata(666)); //the default value
  }

  public int Height
  {
    get { return (int)GetValue(Target.HeightProperty); }
    set { SetValue(Target.HeightProperty, value); }
  }
}



Source source = new Source();
Target target = new Target();

target.Height = 100;

Binding heightBinding = new Binding("Height");
heightBinding.Source = source;
heightBinding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWayToSource;

BindingOperations.SetBinding(target, Target.HeightProperty, heightBinding);

//target.Height and source.Height is now 666 instead of 100 ....
```

Comment: This is definitely a strange behavior. I was able to reproduce it in LINQpad. I would expect that the values would be 100, not 666. Looking forward to seeing the answer.

Comment: copy pasting and debugging your source code, both of properties after step over your last line of code, are 666... strange...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WPF puts Binding as values of dependency properties. When you setting up a binding you actually replaces your current property value with a new one. At the end of the DependencyObject.SetValueCommon you may find a code that did it. There we can see that WPF gets a default value, then set it as a current property value with expression marker, and then attach BindingExpression which updates the source using the current property value - the default value.

```
this.SetEffectiveValue(entryIndex, dp, dp.GlobalIndex, metadata, expression, BaseValueSourceInternal.Local);
object defaultValue = metadata.GetDefaultValue(this, dp);
entryIndex = this.CheckEntryIndex(entryIndex, dp.GlobalIndex);
this.SetExpressionValue(entryIndex, defaultValue, expression);
DependencyObject.UpdateSourceDependentLists(this, dp, array, expression, true);
expression.MarkAttached();
expression.OnAttach(this, dp);
entryIndex = this.CheckEntryIndex(entryIndex, dp.GlobalIndex);
effectiveValueEntry = this.EvaluateExpression(entryIndex, dp, expression, metadata, valueEntry, this._effectiveValues[entryIndex.Index)]);
entryIndex = this.CheckEntryIndex(entryIndex, dp.GlobalIndex);
```

Comment: The main goal is to understand that Binding acts as a value inside DependencyObject. There is very simple solution for your case. You can save the current value before setting the Binding. When Binding is set you should re-assign saved value to target's height.